# APA6 Man-Class, Citation with Biblatex, how do I get "Text (e.g., Source1 and Source2)"?

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa6

I have a question concerning the use of the APA6 Man-Class, combined with Biblatex. Normally, I use `\parencite` or `\textcite` to cite. But now I need something like this:

"Text (e.g., Author1,Year1 and Author2,Year2)" or this: "Text (Text, Author,Year)"

When I try to do the second one with `\parencite`, it looks like this: "Text (Text, (Author,Year))"
And with `\textcite` like this: "Text (Text, Author (Year))"

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try and use normal `\cite`. But maybe there is something better.

Comment: BTW: Can we expect you to use `biblatex-apa` (i.e. `style=apa` as `biblatex` option)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` has two citation commands without brackets: `\cite` and `\nptextcite`, the difference being that the latter has an "&" instead of an "and" between the last two authors.

For your first example

> Text (e.g., Author1, Year1 and Author2, Year2)

you could use

```
Text \parencites[e.g.,][]{sigfridsson}[and][]{cicero}
```

or

```
Text (e.g., \nptextcite{sigfridsson} and \nptextcite{cicero})
```

While for the second case

> Text (Text, Author,Year)

you can use

```
Text \parencite[Text,][]{sigfridsson}
```

But if the "Text" in the parentheses is very long, you might want to use

```
Text (Text, \nptextcite{sigfridsson})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This was exactyl what I was looking for :)