# Cite without brackets but as "Adam & Eva", not "Adam and Eva"

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am using `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` and `\cite` to get rid of the brackets. But I do need the authors to be connected by "&" and not by "and". Is there a way to get this result? - e.g. changing the `\cite` command?

Comment: normally you shouldn't change the apa-style. It follows a specific guide and is quite complex. If you want something different use a more generic style as starting point.

Comment: Is there maybe an existing command to get the desired result?

Comment: `biblatex-apa` tries to implement APA style as closely as possible. And as Ulrike says, APA style is quite complex. In principle APA style has two citation styles (parenthetical and narrative citations) that are represented by `\parencite` and `\textcite`. For proper APA style you should not be using `\cite` as its output does not correspond to anything in the APA manual. If you need the parenthetical citations without the parentheses, use `\nptextcite`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/620942/35864.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472534/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325205/35864.

Comment: That's what I've desperately been looking for. Thank you very much! Please feel free to post an answer!

Comment: Would you be OK with marking your question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/620942/35864 or do you need a separate answer?

Comment: Yes sure - how do I do that?